# Switching the XYZ axes using the tikz-3dplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

This MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
        [tdplot_main_coords,
            cube/.style={very thick,black},
            grid/.style={very thin,gray},
            axis/.style={->,blue,thick}]

    %draw a grid in the x-y plane
    \foreach \x in {-0.5,0,...,2.5}
        \foreach \y in {-0.5,0,...,2.5}
        {
            \draw[grid] (\x,-0.5) -- (\x,2.5);
            \draw[grid] (-0.5,\y) -- (2.5,\y);
        }
            
    %draw the main coordinate frame axes
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=north west]{$y$};
    \draw[axis,tdplot_main_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yields

[image]

I want to rotate the orientation such that:

1. X axis goes to where Y axis is.
2. Y axis goes to where Z axis is.
3. Z axis goes to where X axis is.

I am not sure whether it is not possible or `tikz-3dplot` makes it ridiculously confusing, but I am not able to do it with `\tdplotsetmaincoords{}`

Comment: That does not seem to be possible for the main coordinates. Maybe you could use the rotated coordinate system described under 2.3 in the documentation.

Comment: Note: The image does not belong to the current MWE. The grid should be on the x-y-plane.

Answer (score 1):

After racking my brain a lot, I finally managed to do it. This package uses the Euler angles orientation to shift the image perspective.

There is two coordinate system: the main, which can e shifted by using two angles only, and the rotated coordinate system, which can be shifted by using  three angles. From the documentation, it "explains" why the main coordinate system has only two rotation: "Note that the third row of the rotation matrix is not needed for this transformation, since a screen coordinate is a 2d value." That makes no sense for me, at all.

Anyway, my way out was, maintain the main coordinate system as it is, rotate the rotated coordinate system and use it only. It follow the zyz rotation and seems something like this

[image]

that is the MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        tdplot_main_coords,
        rotated axis/.style={->,orange,thick},
        cube/.style={very thick,black},
        ]
        
    %draw the rotated coordinate frame axes
    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{15}{-20}{-15}%
    \draw[rotated axis, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[anchor=west]{$x'$};
    \draw[rotated axis, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[anchor=south west]{$y'$};
    \draw[rotated axis, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[anchor=west]{$z'$};
    
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) -- (2,2,0) -- (2,0,0) -- cycle;
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,2) -- (0,2,2) -- (2,2,2) -- (2,0,2) -- cycle;
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,2);
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (0,2,0) -- (0,2,2);
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (2,0,0) -- (2,0,2);
    \draw[cube, tdplot_rotated_coords] (2,2,0) -- (2,2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]